# Editing specific CoreData entries

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, core-data

Once again, since Core Data is new to me, I need assistance. Basically, I need to edit a specific Core Data object from a view outside the **tableview**, save it, and reload the tableview. I can manage reloading the tableview, but I cannot figure out how to find the specific Core Data object for that indexPath entry. I don't have any code because I cannot find anything to suit my purpose.

Detail (Editor)

```
-(IBAction)cancel:(id)sender{


    NSLog(@"Sent!");
 //   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
//    [self.view.superview removeFromSuperview];
    OweDetails *details = info.details;


    [info setValue:oField.text forKey:@"name"];

    info.name = oField.text;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:1.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         self.master = [[MasterViewController alloc]init];
                         [self dismissSemiModalViewController:self];
                         [self.master.tableView reloadData];

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"Done!");
                     }];




}
```

Master (TableView)

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"I tapped myself!");

        OweInfo *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.tdModal = [[TDSemiModalViewController alloc]init];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    FooterViewController *fvc = [[FooterViewController alloc]init];
    OweDetails *details = info.details;
    [self.tdModal setDetailItem:info.name];
    [self.tdModal setMoneyItem:details.money];
//    [self.view addSubview:test.view];

    self.tdModal.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;



    self.tdModal.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    OweInfo *info2 = (OweInfo *)[nameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.tdModal.info = info2;



                      [self presentSemiModalViewController:self.tdModal];









}
```

Comment: What do you see? And what do you expect to see instead? You are overspecifying the data sent to `tdModal`: once you've assigned `info` (or `info2`--why are there two copies?), then `tdModal` can ask its `info` object for MOC, `name`, and `details.money`. Are you seeing any view transition at all?

Comment: @HalMueller It sends nothing, the info.name NSLogging on the detail side reports (NULL). It is supposed to say "Jerry", the name in the cell. info.name on the Master side reports the proper name.

Comment: @HalMueller okay, so the passing of data was a rookie mistake, now I need help refreshing the tableview from the detail controller, and making the changes 'stick' as a force close from the switcher kills the changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext* context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];   
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"YOUR_ENTITY_NAME" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SOME_PREDICATE_USED_TO_UNIQUELY_IDENTIFY_YOUR_INDEXPATH ==%@", @"VALUE"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError* error;
NSArray* array = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error fetching data. %@", error);
    return nil;
}

if (array.count != 1)
{
    NSLog(@"Invalid number (%d) of objects found", array.count);
    return nil;
}

return [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

Edit: This is in response to you asking about more details. 
The code above can be its own function. I will give you a simple example of how you can use it.

-- In the VC where you have the table and are displaying the data

1: Let us assume your entity is called MyEntity and that it has an integer unique identifier field called myEntityUniqueId.

2: In your cellForRowAtIndexPath, you would write:

```
cell.tag = myCurrentEntity.myEntityUniqueId
```

-- Now lets go to your other VC where you want to retrieve the instance of MyEntity represented by the cell that was tapped.

1: Write the function:

```
-(void) findMyEntityForId:(int) tappedUniqueId
{
      AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext* context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];   
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"myEntityUniqueId ==%d", tappedUniqueId];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError* error;
NSArray* array = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error fetching data. %@", error);
    return;
}

if (array.count != 1)
{
    NSLog(@"Invalid number (%d) of objects found", array.count);
    return;
}

  MyEntity* foundResult = [array objectAtIndex:0]; // <-- This is the instance you are looking for.
}
```

2: Now call the above function with the correct argument.

I haven't tested the code but it should be fine.

Comment: Let me know if you are having trouble with the part about the predicate used to identify the object represented by the indexPath

Comment: what function do I put this in? It has a return statement. Hmmmm. Can I have a bit more code for context?

Comment: This code, as posted, uses the `NSError` idiom incorrectly. Result in the `&error` parameter is undefined if the fetch succeeds. Test should be `if (!array) {...`.

Comment: Hmm, my logic was that if there is an error then if (error) will catch it. If the array is nil, or has 0 objects or duplicates, then if (array.count != 1) will catch it. Is that wrong?

Comment: Yes, that's wrong. See documentation: 
_error_ 
If there is a problem executing the fetch, upon return contains an instance of `NSError` that describes the problem.
**Return Value**
An array of objects that meet the criteria specified by request fetched from the receiver and from the persistent stores associated with the receiver’s persistent store coordinator. If an error occurs, returns `nil`. If no objects match the criteria specified by request, returns an empty array.

Comment: Then my use is correct. I am saying, if there is an error, print it and return. As for the array, I want only 1 object to match the criteria, so if it's count is not 1, print and return.

Comment: No, it is incorrect. The idiom is `if (!result) { process the error}`. You're doing, instead, `if (error) {process the error}`. In the case of success, though, the contents of `error` are not defined. Your `error` variable could be non-nil even if operation succeeded.

Comment: Oh man. I have 20K+ lines of code with most errors handled this way.. Thank you for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an `NSFetchedResultsController`, ask it for the `objectAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: I would, but I am accessing it from a different VC. However, I am already working on an alternative solution.

Comment: Can you describe your flow in more detail? The general approach should be tap on tableview cell, fire up new VC from XIB or storyboard, then pass the NSManagedObject and MOC to the new VC (either in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` or in `prepareForSegue:`.

Comment: @Hall Mueller well, its a tableview, and when you tap the cell, it adds a subview with fields for editing the data. I updated the main post to show the code I am using now. Its still not working.